# Updating Cgridview with date selected from CJuiDatePicker

Tags: yii

Im newbie to yii,I want to update the CGridview date column with the date selected from datepicker shown in image,

[image]

My View Coding:

```
<?php
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',
    array(
        'name'=>'inline_datepicker',
        'flat' => true, // tells the widget to show the calendar inline

    )
); ?>

  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'editsource-grid',
    'dataProvider'=> Holidays::model()->search(),
    'columns'=>array(   

       'seq',
         array(
        'name'=>'name',            
        'value'=>'Holiday',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>5),

        ),
        'date',
         array(
        'name'=>'is_active',            
        'value'=>'Y',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>5),

        ),  

    ),
)); ?>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I would just suggest making a column in the GridView which has a date picker as a filter. The following code only contains what is needed for it to work:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', [
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:function(){jQUery("#Model_date").datepicker()}',
    'columns' => [
        [
            'name' => 'date',
            'value' => '$data->date',
            'filter' => $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', [
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'date',
            ], true),
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: i dont want to filter the data,just want to set the date value in date column of cgridview while selecting the date from datepicker...

Comment: Can you provide a use case for it (because currently I don't really see a point of selecting a date, showing it in a column, and doing nothing with it, or probably I'm missing something). Then I think your only solution will be writing JavaScript which does what you want after selecting the date from a widget.

Comment: im newbie to yii, can you provide the code for getting date from datepicker and setting it in column of grid?

Comment: I can point you in the right direction, shouldn't be too hard to do it yourself. Just create a datepicker widget, and when using jQuery scripts add an event to check for value changes, if value changes use jQuery to select the elements you want to update with the value and then change it with the one from a datepicker.

Comment: im getting the selected date but dont know how to set it on the cgridview's particular column,can you give some info?

Comment: You should use some selector for getting the element you want (this will depend on your code) and then using `html()` or `text()` method of jQuery you should change the contents of that element. A brief look on the page http://jquery.com shows how to manipulate elements.